# Change the default values by Tensorflow ByteProcessor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used tensorflow.contrib.learn.preprocessing.ByteProcessor to get char_ids, but what it returns is ASCII value of those, what I want is them to start from 1 rather taking ASCII value, I am thinking of using dictionaries to map the ASCII mapping and indexing from 1, but I don't like that method, since it will be very naive and unsophisticated, is there any smart method, to take on this problem, also I'll be using these ids, and converting them to one-hot vector representation for Text Classification.